# How tibco is useful to organizations and why it is used?

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-gi

I am interested in learning tibco.I have found some good videos in youtube but all those are only tutorials.None of the videos answer why tibco is used in organizations and how it is useful to the same.I saw some tutorials in webservices and yes we can do the same using java.

I am basically from java background and have quite good experience in webservices.I saw some tutorials in tibco regarding web services and they are using soap palletes.

Not only for web services I have also seen tutorials for jdbc pallettes.In java also we have jdbc.so many questions arise in my mind and one of the question is why tibco?If java can do which is free then why do buy tibco and do the same work.

In general can anybody please tell me why tibco is used and how does it help in organizations?

I am just new to this tool

Comment: StackOverflow is about programming and programmers tools related questions. If you have questions about programming use of Tibco, they are on topic here. A discussion of Tibco's purpose and benefits is not a programming question.

Comment: @KenWhite You are the senior member here... So I lean on agreeing with you. For my information, is there a stack exchange site for such ramblings?  . Us newbies would like to know where such discussion should take place. (Programming capacities of a integration/programmation framework)

Comment: @KenWhite I am not sure if you have seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893424/how-to-send-email-using-tibco-mail-activity) or not.Please have a look there

Comment: @rocking: The existence of another question related to Tibco does not magically makes yours on-topic just because it's also about Tibco. Yours is a generic "Please describe the product and what it's good for" question; the other is a specific question about a specific task. They're hardly the same thing. I mentioned before: "If you have questions about programming use of Tibco, they are on topic here", and that's still the case. Your question is not about programming use of Tibco.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This could be long...

First thing :
When speaking of TIBCO, 90% of people mean TIBCO BusinessWorks (a.k.a. Activematrix BusinessWorks).

Some context about TIBCO:
BusinessWorks is one of TIBCO's more important products, but nowadays, there are a lot more : Spotfire (an upcoming "tableau"-like analysis and dashboard tool), EMS (a MQ server, JMS compliant but built in C for performance... with easy administration) ServiceGrid (a scalable Java, .Net, BusinessWorks, Mediation integration application server), BusinesEvent (a CEP engine), BPM (based on ServiceGrid), MDM, Silver Fabric (Private cloud provisining tools).

Their product lineup [is extensive](http://www.tibco.com/products/product-index/default.jsp).

Assuming you are considering to work with BusinessWorks. Why should you learn it ?:
Tools such as TIBCO BusinessWorks (or Sofware AG webMethods Integration Server, or IBM IIB, or RedHat Fuse (with open source Camel and Active MQ in back-ground) ) arne used primarely to develop integration solutions in visual "RAD" mode.

Some examples:

- Create web services to expose Database records or (with adapters) a mainframe program.
- Map hundreds of xml fields to a legacy database, and manage exceptions and looping... in mere minutes.
- Catch a JMS event and orchestrate a complex process on managing/broadcasting it.

Business often relies on solutions such as business works to provide a framework around similar integration tasks. This way, IT is not responsible of the framework AND business code, but only of the business code. This of course, is only theory...

BW5 relies on about 300 adapters, that can help businesses integrate with many legacy, standard or cloud applications. (IMS to Evernote ? Check !)

IMHO, Businessworks is one of the best such product in the business, and BW6 seem promising (with a more REST/API orientation).

I hope this helps.

See [this link](https://www.tibcommunity.com/tibco-activematrix-businessworks.html) for a good intro to BW.

Edit : Aside from the classical tech support and training (which is both good with TIBCO), all these solutions typically include features for : Scalability, Availability, Security and other non-functional requirements that a good framework would need ! (This apply to most vendors as well.)

Edit 2 :
To summarize, advantages of BW, are, IMHO:

- Ease of prototyping
- Ease of RAD Developement
- Easy to create complex solutions in specialized fields related to integration, such as:

  - Complex Data mappings (XML or else)
  - Mediation with specialized or legacy systems (SAP, Siebel, IMS, CICS, etc.)
  - Very easy to integrate MQ (all variants of MOMs), DBs (most of them) and create feature ruch web services (SOAP or REST)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Can you please add more details of why to use tibco business works or some thing like benefits of tibco business works or advantages of it?I can get from tibco site about tibco BW but I want to know your personal experience about it

Comment: Thanks again,can you please tell me what all tibco tools you know like EMS,spotfire,BW etc?

Comment: I worked mostly with : EMS, SG, BW. I learned about HAWK, BPM, Spotfire. I look forward to learn more about MDM, Silver Fabric and others.

Comment: do you have gmail so that we can discuss there,Here I dont think we are allowed to talk off topics here

Comment: Look at my website in my profile page. You can join me by using either LinkedIn or the email in my CV. www.ghislaincote.com

Comment: I dont have linkedin ,wow you have so many years of experience.I have only 4 months of experice in IT industry

Comment: Can you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893424/how-to-send-email-using-tibco-mail-activity