# How to send email using tibco mail activity

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I am a beginner is TIBCO.I want to send email using tibco mail activity.Following are my configuration of send mail activity

**host:**  smtp.gmail.com:587
selected the authenticate check box 
then in username field entered my gmail username and in password entered my gmail password.

and in the input tab provided the valid to address,subject and body.When I run then I get the following error

*BW-MAIL-100019 Job-10000 Error in [Sender.process/Send Mail]
Error sending mail message. Cause: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. nx12sm74930440pab.6 - gsmtp*

I have also checked by changing the host like this *smtp.gmail.com:25* but still the same error.Can any body please tell me what wrong am I doing?

Comment: 587 is SMTP/TLS port. 465 is SMTP/SSL port. Have you tried using this port? Also, make sure the Send Mail activity's Trusted Certificates Folder points to a folder containing the whole Gmail certificate chain.

Comment: @NicolasHeitz yes I have tried with 465 port also but it did not work.You said *Also, make sure the Send Mail activity's Trusted Certificates Folder points to a folder containing the whole Gmail certificate chain.* can you tell me how to do this?You can post as answer and I will upvote

Comment: @NicolasHeitz I have tried your way but its not working.Please what do now?Can you send me a project to send email using gmail?

Comment: For some reason, I wasn't able to make it work with SSL (it would require further investigations) but it worked fine with TLS. I will edit my original answer with the resolution details.

Comment: @NicolasHeitz i did as you suggested now i get error `BW-MAIL-100019 Job-18000 Error in [Sender.process/Send Mail]
Error sending mail message. Cause: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. it4sm70296408pbc.39 - gsmtp`

Comment: That must be because your version of BW does not support SSL. Try adding the following properties in the TRA of your application (or in designer.tra if you are testing from Designer, then restart Designer): java.property.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true and
java.property.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true. But I doubt this will work. If it doesn't, you are left with 2 options: 1) Upgrade BW to 5.10 (or later) or 2) Use custom Java code in your BW process (there's a great and working example here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example).

Comment: @NicolasHeitz you said *Try adding the following properties in the TRA of your application* can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you are testing from Designer? If so, add the 2 property lines into `<TIBCO_HOME>\designer\5.x\bin\designer.tra` then restart Designer and test again.

Comment: @NicolasHeitz Is designer.tra is used  for adding any java related properties ?

Comment: In short, designer.tra and bwengine.tra are used for BW engine configuration. You can use them to add Java and BW properties, among others. But this is another topic that we should cover in a dedicated question.

Comment: @NicolasHeitz Thanks for helping.The way you said worked.Hope you will help me in future if I face any problems

Comment: Glad to hear that! Just to be sure, you only added the 2 lines to designer.tra to make it work? Please confirm and I will update my original answer with this tip for those who use a BW version older than 5.10.

Comment: I believe similar questions have already been asked (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569242/how-tibco-is-useful-to-organizations-and-why-it-is-used), but if not, feel free to create a new question so that this thread remains focused on your original post.

Comment: @NicolasHeitz ohh yes and that question has been asked by me.If possible please answer in that question too.I promise I will upvote there also

Comment: @NicolasHeitz I have awarded 50 bounty to your answer,Thanks again

Comment: @NicolasHeitz can you please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925787/why-do-we-use-tibco-mapper-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow these instructions to use the Send Mail activity over TLS (port 587):**

1. First, retrieve the full certificate chain of the SMTP server. To do so, download an OpenSSL client (e.g. [GnuWin32's implementation](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm) if you are on Windows), then type:

   ```
   openssl s_client -showcerts -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp
   ```

   A list of PEM-formatted certs should show up. Copy each of them in a separate file (or all of them in a single file) with extension `.cert` and add those files to any folder in your BW project. Please note that the root CA certificate is missing from the chain; you can download it [here](https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem) and add it to the certs folder. You can also use an external folder if you want the certs to be managed outside your project by using the `BW_GLOBAL_TRUSTED_CA_STORE` global variable (see BW documentation).
2. On the Send Mail activity, set the *Host* field to `smtp.gmail.com:587`.
3. **If using BW 5.8 or below**, add the following Java properties to the TRA of your application:

   ```
   java.property.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
   java.property.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
   ```

   **If using BW 5.10 or above**, check the *SSL* box and make the *Trusted Certificates Folder* point to your certs folder.
4. Check the *Authenticate* box and set the *User Name* (xxxx@gmail.com) and *Password* fields with your Google credentials.

Comment: you said to check ssl box.Where will get the ssl checkbox?I do not have ssl checkbox in configuration tab of send mail activity.I have name,description,host,authenticate,username and password fields in the configuration tab of send mail activity exactly like this tutorial http://tibcoguide.com/how-to-send-email-from-tibco-using-send-mail-activity/

Comment: The SSL checkbox is available since BW 5.10. Which version are you using?

Comment: my bw version is 5.8.0